Angular 17 click event not firing?
I am starting with angular and I have the below code,
app.component.html =>
<div (click)="myFunction()" >{{ title }}</div>
<div>Count is: {{ count }}</div>
<button (click)="updateCount();" type="button">Button</button>

app.component.ts =>
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css',
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular Learn';

  count = 1;

  updateCount() {
    this.count++;
  }

  myFunction() {
    console.log('Title Clicked');
    alert('Title Clicked');
  }
}

These functions defined in the ts file are not firing. No idea what is wrong here. I created my app using npm init @angular angular-learn command.

Please remove standalone and imports from the component, then try again.

Just created another project and everything works fine now, not sure what is the root cause of this issue :(

@JigneshPanchal Standalone components are the new default, so this is not a good recommendation to newbies.
